# C++ - Getting a file from an indirect URL

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am trying to download and parse a web page (It's source code) from an indirect URL. I keep coming accross problems as the functions I am using seem to need a direct link. 
for example:

If I pass the URL "http://www.google.com/index.html" I get googles HTML source

If I pass the URL "http://www.google.com" I get errors

I have tried 3 methods:

1. WinInet's Download function
2. the URLOpenBlockingStream function
3. cURL - had difficulty compiling the cURL libraries for C++ Builder 2010, when I finally got there I kept getting Access Violation Errors.

Is there any easy way of doing this?
I know this is so easy to do in Java/AndroidSDK adn other simple scripters like AHK dont have a problem with it either.

Thanks

Comment: if url does redirection, then with error code it will also provide new URL that point to actual content. You can try downloading that URL.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? Can you add them to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!
    I couldnt get the URLOpenBlockingStream function to work as URLMon was written for VC++ not C++ Builder. After finding URLMon, and converting it to a format compatible with C++builder then adding it to the project I got URLOpenBlockingStream to work correctly.